# Как получить доступ к элементам детям (их dom)?

Tags: reactjs

Как правильно получить все File компоненты?

```
class Files extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  onEvent = () => {
    this.allFiles; // ?? вот тут нужно получить всех детей, а точнее определенные dom элементы  у каждого
  };

  render() {
    const files = this.props.files;
    return (
      <div className="uploader-file-system-panel">
        {files.map(item => {
          return (
            <File
              key={item.id}
              id={item.id}
              folder={item.folder}
              title={item.title}
            />
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: У `File` класс объявить. А потом взять все эти элементы `ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this).getElementsByClassName('your_class')`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Каждому элементу File задать ref и поместить ссылки в объект allFiles

```
class Files extends Component {
  allFiles = {};

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  onEvent = () => {
    this.allFiles; // Будет содержать объект всех DOM элементов
    this.allFiles['someId'].toggle("mystyle"); // Переключит стиль у элемента с id = 'someId'
  };

  render() {
    const files = this.props.files;
    return (
      <div className="uploader-file-system-panel">
        {files.map(item => {
          return (
            <File
              ref={r => this.fileRefs[item.id] = r}
              key={item.id}
              id={item.id}
              folder={item.folder}
              title={item.title}
            />
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```